# como mostrar un directorio en forma de acordeón?

Tags: php, html5

tengo el siguiente código que recorre un directorio y lo almacena en un arreglo. mi idea es mostrar el directorio en forma de acordeón y dentro de este sus archivos, y en caso de tener subcarpetas que las muestre en forma de acordeón dentro de la carpeta padre.
para el acordeón estoy usando el siguiente:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol

```
//función para obtener el nombre de las carpetas y los archivos en array multidimensional
function dirToArray($dir) {
    //creo un array
    $listDir = array();
    //abro los directorios contenidos en $dir
    if($handler = opendir($dir)) {
        //leo todos los elementos contenidos 
        while (($file = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
            //verifico que hayan elementos
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != ".DS_Store") {
                /*si los elementos son archivos, guardo los elementos 
                en algún indice (dimensión) del array*/
                if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) {
                    $listDir[] = $file;
                /*si los elementos son directorios, guardo los elementos 
                en otro índice o dimensión, repitiendo hasta que hayan elementos*/
                }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$file)){
                    $listDir[$file] = dirToArray ($dir."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handler);
    }
    return $listDir;
}

$dir = $directorio;
$listDir = dirToArray($dir);

//mostrar el arreglo del directorio
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($listDir);
echo '</pre>';
```

no sé de qué manera recorrer el arreglo para mostrarlo como acordeón. les dejo un ejemplo de mi directorio

carpet2020 (esta seria la raiz)

- Enero
- - carpeta1
- - - archivo.xlsx
- - carpeta2
- - Archivo.jpg
- - archivo.xlsx
- Febrero
- Marzo

Answer (score 0):

he realizado lo siguiente, pero no muestra todos los archivos

```
foreach ($listDir as $listDir => $detalles) {
    if (!is_array($listDir)) {
        echo "<button class=\"accordion\"><i class=\"fas fa-folder-open fa-3x mr-2 text-warning\"></i>$listDir</button>";
    }
    foreach ($detalles as $indice => $valor) {
        if (is_array($valor)) {
            echo "<div class=\"panel\"><p><button class=\"accordion\"><i class=\"fas fa-folder-open fa-3x mr-2 text-warning\"></i>$indice</button></p></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"panel\"><p>$valor</p></div>";
        }
    }
}
```